# When i try to perform the below DML queries using sqldf function in R, it throws me an error message

Tags: r

```
sqldf("Insert into Final (Prod_cat_code, prod_subcat_code) VALUES (30, 30); ")
```

Error message:

> data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
>
> Warning message:
>   In result_fetch(res@ptr, n = n) :
>     Don't need to call dbFetch() for statements, only for queries

Comment: That is a warning message from RSQLite. You can ignore that warning. It is not an error message. Unrelated to that, note that insert does not return anything so the insert statement will have no effect in R. You need sqldf(c("insert ...", "select * from main.Final")) to actually return something back to R.  FAQ#8 on the sqldf github site update discusses the return issue with respect to update and the same thing applies to insert.

Comment: Thanks Grothendieck. The below code helps and works perfectly                                                     
Final <- sqldf(c("Insert into Final (Prod_cat_code, prod_subcat_code) VALUES (50, 20) ", "select * from main.Final"))

Comment: In the similar pattern, when i try to use subquery it throws me an error                            sqldf(c("Insert into ( select prod_cat_code, prod_subcat_code, Qty, total_amt from Final) VALUES (0, 0, 555, 99999)", "select * from main.Final"))

Comment: That is a different problem.  The correct syntax, which we illustrate using the builtin `BOD` data frame, is `sqldf(c("insert into BOD(Time, demand) values (10, 90)", 
"select * from main.BOD"))`

Comment: So if i' understand correctly. when we use a sub-query with in a insert command  in sqldf function. it will not work ?

Comment: Yes, you have to tell it what table you want to insert into, not a query.